# generate basic pie chart using chartjs

Tags: jquery, chart.js

I am using [ChartJs](https://www.chartjs.org/) library to generate a very basic pie chart. I just want to display two data `AAA` and `BBB` labeled but code bellow not creating any pie chart and even not getting any error. How can i fix it? Whats wrong i am doing here?

Html:

```
<canvas id="LossProfit"></canvas>
```

ChartJs:

```
<script>

    var LossProfit = document.getElementById('LossProfit').getContext('2d');
    var myPieChart = new Chart(LossProfit, {
        type: 'pie',
        data: [
            {
                label: 'AAA',
                value: 20,
                color: "#1a5279"
            },
            {
                label: 'BBB',
                value: 40,
                color: "#1a5279"
            }
        ],
        options: {
            responsive: true
        }
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [Chart.js documentation](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/doughnut.html#data-structure):

> For a pie chart, datasets need to contain an array of data points. The data points should be a number, Chart.js will total all of the numbers and calculate the relative proportion of each.
>
> You also need to specify an array of labels so that tooltips appear correctly.

Please have a look at your amended code below that works fine now.

```js
new Chart(document.getElementById('LossProfit'), {
  type: 'pie',
  data: {
    labels: ['AAA', 'BBB'],
    datasets: [{
      data: [20, 40],
      backgroundColor: ["#1a5279", "#f78159"]
    }],
  },
  options: {
    responsive: true
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="LossProfit" height="100"></canvas>
```